# Spark - Exception in task

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Using Spark, I am analysing a YouTube dataset to find the top five categories with the maximum number of videos uploaded.

Load the data:

```
val textRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/spark/youtubedata.txt")
```

First Line of the RDD

```
textRDD.first
res268: String = QuRYeRnAuXM    EvilSquirrelPictures    1135    Pets & Animals  252 1075    4.96    46  86  gFa1YMEJFag nRcovJn9xHg 3TYqkBJ9YRk rSJ8QZWBegU 0TZqX5MbXMA UEvVksP91kg ZTopArY7Nbg 0RViGi2Rne8 HT_QlOJbDpg YZev1imoxX8 8qQrrfUTmh0 zQ83d_D2MGs u6_DQQjLsAw 73Wz9CQFDtE
```

Created a RDD by extracting the 4th column

```
val countRDD = textRDD.map( line => line.split("\t")(3))
```

Created a pair

```
val pairRDD = countRDD.map(x => (x,1))
```

Till here everything was working fine.
The final step is to retrieve the top 5 from the list

```
val result = pairRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _).sortByKey(false).take(5)
```

The above step is returning the below error:

```
17/06/07 07:55:59 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 262.0 (TID 245) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 
at $line486.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:32)
at $line486.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:32)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
. 
.
.
```

Where could I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were null values in some lines in the dataset.
So, i modified the code which gave the correct result without any error.

```
val countRDD = textRDD.map(line => {val temp = line.split("\t"); if(temp.length >= 3)temp(3)})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is **not** in the final line where you perform `take` but in the following line

```
val countRDD = textRDD.map( line => line.split("\t")(3))
```

When a file is read using `textFile` api, all the lines are converted to `string`, thus the `\t` (tab) is not preserved. And you cannot split using `"\t"`

Above statement is just a `transformation` so no error was thrown but when `take`, an `action`, was performed error was thrown.

**You will have to either edit the input file by inserting splitting characters (Strings) on sides of expected string for K or you will have to find appropriate method for splitting the lines read.**

Comment: What do you mean by "_When a file is read using textFile api, all the lines are converted to string, thus the \t (tab) is not preserved._"

Comment: @philantrovert What I meant was that \t (tab) would be treated as series of spaces. isn't that so?

Answer (score 0):

change plain "\t" split to line.split("\s+");

The \s is equivalent to [ \t\n\x0B\f\r] and should resolve the issue.